# problem with httpClient get method for my private shopify API using Angular

Tags: angular, api, shopify

I have a problem with httpClient get method for my private shopify API.
The problem is that my API has Authentication keys and I need help consuming it on my Angular app. I am sharing the api link,
I have tested it in postman and it's working well,
but when I want to consume this API with my Angular App,
I get a problem with the authorization COR. I have all the secret code, but I don't know how to use them in my Angular app.
Here is the link of the API that has all the orders:
https://24b31e2389f78e7aab8830c7f18b031e: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@rachid-store11.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/orders.json

**API KEY:** 24b31e2389f78e7aab8830c7f18b031e -
**password:** 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 -
**shared secret:** 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

Comment: you need to enable CORS on server to accept request from you client browser. you can check related issue here. https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/API-Working-in-Postman-ERROR-Shopify-blocked-by-CORS-policy-No/td-p/668650

Answer (score 0):

Hy, call api from code like this

using axios

```
axios.get('https://<shop-name>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/orders.json?status=any', {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/Json', 'X-Shopify-Access-Token': <app-token>}})
```

must include app token by same header name like ***X-Shopify-Access-Token*** and your token string start from Sh.........